# Azure VM Inbound Throttling to VMs?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

We have 2 Elastic VMs (Linux) (Currently DS2V2) behind an Azure Load Balancer.   We are doing HTTP Posts from our local lan into the Load Balancer, but we seem to be getting throttled.  We have tried:  Changing the size of the VMs, no difference; adding additional premium SSDs, again no difference; running multiple threads on our end, again no differenece.

What we did do though, was to having the Elastic Engine suck in all of the log files from the Linux boxes and the index rate jump pretty high while it was ingesting them.  So we are assuming that it's not really the Linux Elastic boxes that are throttling us.

We do have Kibana installed on the boxes, and as a base line, we're just using the "Cluster Indexing Rate" for both our local posts to the box, and the local ingestion of the log files.

We do understand that yes, there is going to be some latency and overhead since we are now involving the internet, but not the rates we are currently getting.   (We have a 1G pipe to the internet, it's nowhere near capacity, so we can rule out at least getting out of our company).

The question is, where else can we look to determine where we might be getting throttled?

Comment: Have you allowed the HTTP ports in the network security groups which are attaching to your backend Azure VM network interfaces or subnets? You could find it from virtual machine---networking---inbound port rules on the azure portal.

Comment: Yep.   I have traffic all the way through.   It's just MUCH slower via the internet then it is on the local machines.

Answer (score 0):

For the performance "MUCH slower", it is a bit subjective question and hard to identify. I just provide some information that may impact it.

Azure Compute requests may be throttled at a subscription and on a per-region basis. If you have an API throttling error, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-throttling-errors) to troubleshoot throttling issues, and best practices to avoid being throttled.

Some factors CPU and storage limits that differ on Azure VM sizes may impact the Azure VM to process incoming data. You may change the size to a higher CPU and premium SSD disk. You could also change Azure resources to another region which is close to your location. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput).